# Delphi IPWorks LDAP PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE

Tags: active-directory, ldap, delphi-xe2, windows-server-2012-r2, ipworks

I am using Delphi 10.3 and IPWorks LDAP component. I can modify most attributes without any issues, such as `unicodePwd`, `givenName`, and `mail`.  However, for the `userAccountControl` attribute of a user, I am unable to set `ADS_UF_PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE`, of course after successfully binding as an administrator with secure connection and supplying correct DN, because if the connection is not secure, it is impossible to modify the password:

```
const
  ADS_UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT = 512;
  ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD = 65536;
  ADS_UF_PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE = 64;
  ADS_UF_LOCKOUT = 16;

ipaLDAP1.DN := searchResultDN;
ipaLDAP1.AttrCount := 1;
ipaLDAP1.AttrType[0] := 'userAccountControl';
ipaLDAP1.AttrValue[0] := IntToStr(ADS_UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT + ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD + ADS_UF_LOCKOUT + ADS_UF_PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE);
ipaLDAP1.AttrModOp[0] := amoReplace;

ipaLDAP1.Modify();
```

It is strange that I can not modify `ADS_UF_PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE`. It doesn't take effect on the user.  When I check the user, this attribute is still unchecked. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

`userAccountControl` is a bitmask, so you should be using the `or` operator to combine flags, not the `+` operator.

But, more importantly, according to [How to use the UserAccountControl flags to manipulate user account properties](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/305144/how-to-use-useraccountcontrol-to-manipulate-user-account-properties):

> PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE
>   Note: **You cannot assign this permission by directly modifying the UserAccountControl attribute**. For information about how to set the permission programmatically, see the "Property flag descriptions" section.

Where the "Property flag descriptions" section says:

> - PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE - The user cannot change the password. This is a permission on the user's object. **For information about how to programmatically set this permission, visit the following Web site**:
>
>   [Modifying User Cannot Change Password (LDAP Provider)](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/library/aa746398.aspx)

That page, in turn, says:

> The ability of a user to change their own password is a permission that can be grant or denied. **To deny this permission, set two ACEs in the security descriptor discretionary access control list (DACL) of the user object with the ADS_ACETYPE_ACCESS_DENIED_OBJECT ace type**. One ACE denies the permission to the user and another ACE denies the permission to the Everyone group. Both ACEs are object-specific deny ACEs that specify the GUID of the extended permission for changing passwords. **To grant this permission, set the same ACEs with the ADS_ACETYPE_ACCESS_ALLOWED_OBJECT ace type**.
>
> **The following procedure describes how to modify or add ACEs for this permission.**
>
> To modify or add the ACEs for this permission
>
> 1. Bind to the user object.
> 2. Obtain the `IADsSecurityDescriptor` object from the `ntSecurityDescriptor` property of the user object.
> 3. Obtain an `IADsAccessControlList` interface for the security descriptor from the `IADsSecurityDescriptor.DiscretionaryAcl` property.
> 4. Enumerate the ACEs for the object and search for the ACEs that have the change password GUID (`{AB721A53-1E2F-11D0-9819-00AA0040529B}`) for the `IADsAccessControlEntry.ObjectType` property and "Everyone" or "NT AUTHORITY\SELF" for the `IADsAccessControlEntry.Trustee` property.
>
>    Note: The "Everyone" and "NT AUTHORITY\SELF" strings are localized based on the language of the first domain controller in the domain. Because of this, the strings should not be used directly. The account names should be obtained at run time by calling the `LookupAccountSid` function with the SID for "Everyone" ("S-1-1-0") and "NT AUTHORITY\SELF" ("S-1-5-10") well-known security principals. The `GetSidAccountName`, `GetSidAccountName_Everyone`, and `GetSidAccountName_Self` C++ example functions shown in [Reading User Cannot Change Password (LDAP Provider)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/reading-user-cannot-change-password-ldap-provider) demonstrate how to do this.
> 5. Modify the `IADsAccessControlEntry.AceType` property of the ACEs that were found to `ADS_ACETYPE_ACCESS_DENIED_OBJECT` if the user cannot change their password or `ADS_ACETYPE_ACCESS_ALLOWED_OBJECT` if the user can change their password.
> 6. If the "Everyone" ACE is not found, create a new `IADsAccessControlEntry` object that contains the property values shown in the table below and add the new entry to the ACL with the `IADsAccessControlList.AddAce` method.
> 7. If the "NT AUTHORITY\SELF" ACE is not found, create a new `IADsAccessControlEntry` object with the same property values shown in the table below except the Trustee property contains the account name for SID "S-1-5-10" ("NT AUTHORITY\SELF"). Add the entry to the ACL with the `IADsAccessControlList.AddAce` method.
> 8. To update the `ntSecurityDescriptor` property of the object, call the `IADs.Put` method with the same `IADsSecurityDescriptor` obtained in Step 2.
> 9. Commit the local changes to the server with the `IADs.SetInfo` method.
> 10. If either of the ACEs were created, you must reorder the ACL so that the ACEs are in the correct order. To do this, call the `GetNamedSecurityInfo` function with the LDAP ADsPath of the object and then the `SetNamedSecurityInfo` function with the same DACL. This reordering will occur automatically when the ACEs are added.
>
> The following table lists the `IADsAccessControlEntry` object property values.
>
> `AccessMask`
>   `ADS_RIGHT_DS_CONTROL_ACCESS`
>
> `AceType`
>   `ADS_ACETYPE_ACCESS_DENIED_OBJECT` if the user cannot change their password or `ADS_ACETYPE_ACCESS_ALLOWED_OBJECT` if the user can change their password.
>
> `AceFlags`
>   0
>
> `Flags`
>   `ADS_FLAG_OBJECT_TYPE_PRESENT`
>
> `ObjectType`
>   "{AB721A53-1E2F-11D0-9819-00AA0040529B}" which is the change password GUID in string form.
>
> `InheritedObjectType`
>   Not used
>
> `Trustee`
>   Account name for SID "S-1-1-0" (Everyone).

There is a fairly lengthy code example provided on the same page.

Comment: thank you for your prompt answer, but I swear I don't know how to modify my code to do what you have said, I think I will try to see if I can modify ADS_ACETYPE_ACCESS_DENIED_OBJECT in my code same way I did with other attributes.

Comment: Did you look at the code example provided in the docs I linked to?  The code is in C, but it can be translated to Delphi.  It is a lengthy example, I just didn't take the time to translate it for you.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't know C, I barely know some delphi. I will try to understand the code in C.

Comment: can you please help porting the necessary code to delphi, your help is appreciated, also other members will find this code very useful, not just me, thanks again. I do wish there is a complete component to deal with LDAP in delphi, really!